# DotVVM: Auto-update based on timer

Tags: dotvvm

We have a dotvvm app that displays real-time data.  We would like to have this updated every 5 seconds.  It is loaded in the InitializeAsync Method:

```
 public override async Task PreRender()
    {
        if (!Context.IsPostBack)
            await InitializeAsync();

        await base.PreRender();
    }
```

This sets UsersTotal which is used in the dotHtml:

```
<span IncludeInPage="{value: HasUsers}">{{value: UsersTotal}}</span>
```

We want to refresh this not after the user clicks a button, but automatically.  All the binding options appear to base based on some event.  Does anybody know of a way to accomplish this within the DotVVM framework?  Or is there some official way to implement this with a timer in javascript?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in timer component, but there are several ways to accomplish this.

### JS directive

The most over-powered way of accomplishing this is to use the DotVVM 3 @js directive to link a JS file into your page and then trigger a NamedCommand from JS. Full documentation is here: https://www.dotvvm.com/docs/3.0/pages/concepts/client-side-development/js-directive/call-dotvvm-from-js. The Javascript you need is (roughly) this:

```js
export default context => {

    setInterval(function () { context.namedCommands["Refresh"]() }, 5000)

    return {
        // declare additional JS commands here
    }
}
```

Then use a `NamedCommand` component in the page with your refresh command:

```
<dot:NamedCommand Name="Refresh" Command={command: RefreshData()} />
```

However, you should prefer to use a [staticCommand](https://www.dotvvm.com/docs/3.0/pages/concepts/respond-to-user-actions/static-commands) binding for background jobs.

```
@service myUsersService = Full.Name.Of.MyUsersService

<dot:NamedCommand Name="Refresh" Command={staticCommand: UsersTotal = myUsersService.FetchUsersTotal()} />
```

### Hidden button

While the `@js` directive is a powerful feature, I'd say that for your use case, it would be simpler add a hidden button with this command and trigger it from JS.

```
<dot:Button Click={staticCommand: same as above} Visible=false ID="refreshButton" />

<dot:InlineScript>

setInternal(function () { document.getElementById("refreshButton").click() }, 5000)

</dot:InlineScript>
```

### HTML meta tag

Even simpler way is to use the `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >`, it will instruct the browser to reload the entire page every 5 sec. Works even without JS, but is only acceptable if you don't mind the page is always refreshing.